# How to set EditText hint font transparency?

Tags: android, android-widget

how can I set EditText hint font transparency to 20%?

evilone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've not tested this, but you could set the text color to something like "#DDAAAAAA" The two *D*s set the alpha color, and I think DD should be around 20%. I've not tested it, it could be wrong but it's worth a try!